# Vuetify data table doesn't show when I fetch data from a vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I am fetching the items of a vuetify data-table from a treeview in the sidebar with a getter on vuex store from the active treeview item property. But even the item on treeview comes as active by default, datatable doesn't show without clicking on treeview item and activate it again. How can I solve this problem?

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers0"
  :items="parseData"
  item-key="name"
  v-model="selected0"
  show-select
  expand-icon
  :pagination.sync="pagination"
  class="elevation-2" 
  fixed-header
></v-data-table>
```

parseData is a function under computed:

```
computed: {    
parseData() {
  return this.$store.getters.getCurrFolder;
} }
```

Comment: Can you plan a console.log to log the parseData and provide the logged data structure

Comment: how are you storing/determining/updating the "active" item? sounds like something getCurrFolder needs access to isn't being set until clicking on an item